# IPython notebook fails to open any notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I was using ipython notebook (packages in Anaconda-2.1.0 or Canopy-1.4.1) in "Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise" with browser (latest version of chrome or firefox). It was working perfectly.

Once another user has started ipython notebook in his account. At first, his ipython notebook was failed to run any notebook. The worst is that my ipython was also failed to open or create any notebook after restart the kernel. The windows popup a dialog of "Problem signature" with following information:

---

Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    538f8ffc
  Fault Module Name:    oleshell874.dll
  Fault Module Version: 8.7.4.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   54448aac
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000000000004867
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.274.10
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: a481
  Additional Information 2: a481c64a34722f1c689be57b64ee6a54
  Additional Information 3: 3393
  Additional Information 4: 33936ce55b0e8b96f5dce6a43fae2e99

---

Even I reinstalled the Anaconda or Canopy and restarted the system, it won't help. I have tried to google the Fault Module (oleshell874.dll) but it shows no result.
Please help!

Comment: The fact that googling `oleshell874.dll` gives no search hits is rather disturbing. I start by trying to find out who owns this file in the first place.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Did you mean the ownership of this file in windows? I found that it is owned by Administrator (file location: "C:\Windows\SysWOW64" or "C:\Windows\System32").

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear - I think the first step is to find out who installed this file. That's what I meant with `owner`. Maybe there's some metadata stored in that file, which could give you some clues.

Comment: How can I trace that? Is it a default file with windows?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just tried to google "oleshell dll" and found this file is not related to ipython and windows. The ipython works again after I've renamed this file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment. I just tried to google "oleshell dll" and found this file is not related to ipython and windows. The ipython works again after I've renamed this file.